# Как связать Bounds динамически созданных контролов (Windows Forms)

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, progress-bar

Суть:
Появилось у меня желание слегка кастомизировать `ListView`, путём прикручивания к его `Subitems[ind]` элемента `ProgressBar`, и в целом само по себе прикручивание я кое-как реализовал (см. скриншот)[image: ListView с ProgressBar-ами]

### Код добавления элемента списка с ProgressBar-ом:

```
private void btAdd_click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    var item = new ListViewItem("Test");
    var progressSubitem = new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem();
    var pb = new ProgressBar();

    progressSubitem.Tag = pb; // За это не ругайте
    lvFilesList.Controls.Add(pb);
    item.SubItems.Add(progressSubitem);
    lvFilesList.Items.Add(item);
    
    pb.Bounds = progressSubitem.Bounds;
}
```

Прикольно? Прикольно. Но тут появился вопрос: Если я захочу изменить ширину колонки `ListView`-а, то мои `ProgressBar`-ы должны как-то об этом узнать, и соответствующим образом на мои действия отреагировать. Было решено попробовать пойти в лоб, и циклами перебрать каждый `ListViewItem` моего `ListView`, и каждый `ListViewSubItem` моих `ListViewItem`-ов в событии `ColumnWidthChanging` `ListView`-а (звучит вся эта конструкция ужасно):

### Код обновления размеров всех ProgressBar-ов

```
private void lvFilesList_ColumnWidthChanging(object sender, ColumnWidthChangingEventArgs e) {
            ProgressBar instantBar;
            foreach (ListViewItem item in lvFilesList.Items) {
                foreach (ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem subitem in item.SubItems) {
                    instantBar = (subitem.Tag as ProgressBar);
                    if (instantBar != null) {
                        instantBar.Bounds = subitem.Bounds;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

И это в принципе работает при небольшом количестве записей в списке, и все размеры изменяются адекватно. Но как только список разрастается - начинаются (вполне ожидаемо для такого подхода) тормоза.

А теперь вопрос: Как правильно изменить Bounds каждого `ProgressBar`-а в соответствии с `Bounds` соответствующего ему `Subitem`-а? Ведь по-любому должен быть другой, более быстрый и эффективный способ решить эту проблему, но я его просто не знаю. Заранее спасибо.

P.S.: Сторонние штуки желательно не предлагать

Бонусом: Наглядная иллюстрация проблемы
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Увы, на скорость работы это не повлияло ровным счётом никак

Comment: [Вот такая штука есть](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25648710/12888024), лечит тормоза при отрисовке. Просто добавьте этот метод в класс формы, вызывать его не надо.

Comment: @aepot , Боюсь это не то что мне нужно. Проблема не в мерцании, а в том, что когда я изменяю размер всех ProgressBar-ов одновременно, то нагрузка на ЦП возрастает очень сильно. Даже при использовании подписки на событие (вариант предложенный выше) это происходит. Я обновил вопрос добавив гифку в конце

Comment: Ну к сожалению отрисовка прогресс-бара с анимацией - штука тяжелая для системы. можно например делать виртуально скриншот области с прогресс-барами, сами прогресс-бары прятать, и визуально тянуть картинку, а как пользователь отпустит мышь - отрисовать прогресс-бары. Либо еще какой костыль придумать. Но двойная буферизация, что я выше предложил, она не только мерцания лечит, но и тормоза. Вы попробовали? Есть еще всякие `SuspendLayout()`. А на крайний случай (если ничего не помогает) есть WPF :)